# Can't alter sql object because it's being referenced by default constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-functions, idempotent

I have this script to store a function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName(@SysName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SId AS INT
    SELECT @SId = Id FROM [hyper].[Supplier] WHERE SystemName = @SysName
    RETURN @SId
END
```

I then use it in a default constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [h360_order].[ExternalStore] 
ADD SupplierId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_ExternalStore_SupplierId 
DEFAULT(order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName('Name'));
```

Now the CREATE OR ALTER is for idempotence, but when running the scripts a second time I get the error:

> SQL Error [3729][S0003]: Cannot ALTER 'order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName' because it is being referenced by object 'DF_ExternalStore_SupplierId'.

`IF EXISTS...` seems to be a possibility, but I'm not being able to use it inside the script that creates the function.

How can I fix it cleanly while still keeping idempotence?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. If you want to `ALTER` the function `order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName` then you need to `DROP` the `CONSTRAINT` first. Why, however, are you not using a `FOREIGN KEY` here?

Comment: @Larnu it's a complicated issue, these Ids exist across multiple DBs, long story short, CTO does not want this to be a FK.

Comment: Does the CTO have a good reason for this, other than to make a simple problem difficult?

Comment: @Larnu this supplier Id comes from another DB, it's supposed to add the default id but not make it deppendant of the primary key.

Comment: @MatBailie the Supplier table belongs to another domain / business area, it's not supposed to be deppendant. Anyway, I don't think it would be advised to ask the boss to do it himself.

Comment: Life is learning how to tell the boss that they simply can't have two contradictory requirements.  I do it all the time, and my teams often have to do it to me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the constraint, alter the function, recreate the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [h360_order].[ExternalStore] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_ExternalStore_SupplierId ;


ALTER FUNCTION order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName(@SysName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SId AS INT
    SELECT @SId = Id FROM [hyper].[Supplier] WHERE SystemName = @SysName
    RETURN @SId
END;


ALTER TABLE [h360_order].[ExternalStore] 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ExternalStore_SupplierId 
DEFAULT(order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName('Name')) FOR [SupplierId];
```

Comment: Thanks for you r answer, seems iteresting but these are not idempotent, these will fail if constraint doesn't exist in the first case, and if it does in the second, I could add ifs, but since there are migration scripts it would be a pain to check all this, and not very clean

Comment: What do you think about my solution?

Comment: @anastaciu it's a pretty good solution. If it works for you, feel free to accept your own answer once SO allows it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't like that very much, yours is also a very good answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `sp_executesql` stored procedure within an `IF` statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName') IS NULL
BEGIN

DECLARE @sqlstatement NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @sqlstatement = 
    'CREATE FUNCTION h360_order.GetSupplierIdBySystemName(@SysName AS VARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SId AS INT
        SELECT @SId = Id FROM [hyper].[Supplier] WHERE SystemName = @SysName
        RETURN @SId
    END'
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement;                  
END
```

So basically what this does is check if the stored function exists, and if not it creates one using the sql query stored in `@sqlstatement` through the stored procedure `sp_executesql`, very simple stuff, actually. Finding the right tool for the job is the complicated part.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.